# set sprite dimensions

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Code

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source="MSBack.swf")]
    private var SomeClass:Class;

        public function Test()
        {
            addChild(new SomeClass());
            addChild(txtFld);

            this.height = 100;
            this.width  = 100;

            txtFld.text = width.toString() + " " + height.toString();

        }
    }
}
```

addChild(new SomeClass()) loads a swf background image having width = 100, and height = 100. My problem is that the above code does not show the whole background image. The right and bottom parts are missing. However the textfield displays the 100 100. which is the value i am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm,
Beware, setting width and height of an object in Flash will SCALE the object.

This could be the issue you are facing.

Comment: actually the background appears more bigger than it should be. That's why the lower and right sections of the background do not appear. They overflow the 100 by 100 dimension i have set.

Comment: I am not sure the mechanics of what you are discribing? Is it overflowing or getting clipped (the right and bottom parts are not showing). And the reason its getting clipped is it because of the swf frame its sitting in (the swf is 100x100 displayed on a webpage?). The question becomes, is it getting clipped because of the x,y displacement, or its the wrong scale?